# activerecord-postgis-adapter returns string instead of geometry after saving the record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgis, rgeo

I'm having an issue when retrieving the value of a geometry column from the database. I save an `RGeo::Cartesian::PolygonImpl` instance, reload the record, and when I retrieve the value, I get a `String` instead of a Geometry.

My `config/database.yml` has:

```
development: 
  adapter: postgis
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 10
  timeout: 5000
  schema_search_path: public
  database: XXXX
  username: XXXX
  password: XXXX
```

My table has the following column definition:

```
CREATE TABLE properties
# ...
parcel geometry(Polygon,3785),
# ...
```

And my model has the following setup:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base

  set_rgeo_factory_for_column(:parcel, RGeo::Geographic.simple_mercator_factory(srid: 3785))
  # ...
end
```

Through Rails console, I am creating a polygon and saving it to the DB (output abridged for brevity):

```
2.1.5 :052 > f = Property.rgeo_factory_for_column(:parcel)
2.1.5 :053 > points_array = [{"latitude"=>49.130917114292146, "longitude"=>-122.85873269458159}, {"latitude"=>49.131504470050885, "longitude"=>-122.85873269458159}, {"latitude"=>49.131504470050885, "longitude"=>-122.85743450541838}, {"latitude"=>49.130917114292146, "longitude"=>-122.85743450541838}, {"latitude"=>49.130917114292146, "longitude"=>-122.85873269458159}]
2.1.5 :054 > points = points_array.collect {|p| f.point(p['longitude'], p['latitude'])}
2.1.5 :055 > projection = f.polygon(f.linear_ring(points)).projection
2.1.5 :056 > property = Property.find(123)
2.1.5 :057 > property.parcel = projection
 => #<RGeo::Cartesian::PolygonImpl:0xb82223c "POLYGON ((-13676571.563067732 6297104.554633035, -13676571.563067732 6297204.480123126, -13676427.049311131 6297204.480123126, -13676427.049311131 6297104.554633035, -13676571.563067732 6297104.554633035))">
2.1.5 :058 > property.save!
2.1.5 :059 > property.parcel.class
 => RGeo::Cartesian::PolygonImpl
```

At this point, if I get the value of `property.parcel`, I correctly get the `RGeo::Cartesian::PolygonImpl`. However, if I now reload the record, I get a String:

```
2.1.5 :060 > property.reload
2.1.5 :061 > p.parcel
 => "0103000020C90E000001000000050000009FA6047203166AC18F1B7F23840558419FA6047203166AC15956BA1E9D055841F0F49361F1156AC15956BA1E9D055841F0F49361F1156AC18F1B7F23840558419FA6047203166AC18F1B7F2384055841"
2.1.5 :062 > p.parcel.class
 => String
```

Now, an interesting thing to notice is that if I use `#pluck` on an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, I *do* get the RGeo polygon:

```
2.1.5 :069 > props = Property.where('parcel is not null').limit(1)
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Property id: 37362, parcel: "0103000020C90E0000010000000700000050550F59F9C35EC0...">]>
2.1.5 :070 > props[0].parcel
 => "0103000020C90E0000010000000700000050550F59F9C35EC0F3C61F98209B4840F2A22041F9C35EC0698E70A32C9B484094FF2041F9C35EC0DA12B4A52C9B484048F5426AFCC35EC03C9ED6B02C9B48405079426AFCC35EC0B7EDD1AD2C9B4840E0E72F82FCC35EC0C0BA55A3209B484050550F59F9C35EC0F3C61F98209B4840"
2.1.5 :071 > props.collect(&:parcel)
 => ["0103000020C90E0000010000000700000050550F59F9C35EC0F3C61F98209B4840F2A22041F9C35EC0698E70A32C9B484094FF2041F9C35EC0DA12B4A52C9B484048F5426AFCC35EC03C9ED6B02C9B48405079426AFCC35EC0B7EDD1AD2C9B4840E0E72F82FCC35EC0C0BA55A3209B484050550F59F9C35EC0F3C61F98209B4840"]
2.1.5 :072 > props.pluck(:parcel)
 => [#<RGeo::Geographic::ProjectedPolygonImpl:0xac42e08 "POLYGON ((-123.06209398744 49.2119321971094, -123.062088281509 49.2122997569648, -123.062088281846 49.2123000268236, -123.062281194104 49.2123013542118, -123.062281193653 49.2123009944002, -123.062286898406 49.2119335335351, -123.06209398744 49.2119321971094))">]
```

So I believe there is an issue with Rails not knowing to cast the value into a Geometry when accessed via the column accessor, but I'm not entirely sure why this is happening.

My project has the following setup:

- Ruby 2.1.5
- Rails 4.1.8
- activerecord-postgis-adapter 2.2.1
- rgeo 0.3.20
- rgeo-activerecord 2.0.0
- Postgres 9.3.5
- PostGIS 2.1.4

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with `activerecord-postgis-adapter` for a while now too after upgrading a rails project. PostGIS data in Rails seems to be a finicky beast no matter what library you use (I've got about 3 dozen browser tabs open on the issue right now). I've noticed that one problem that is easy to overlook is if the `rgeo` gem couldn't locate the geos library when it was built. You can test this from your rails console:

```
require 'rgeo'
RGeo::Geos.supported?
```

If that returns false, then that could be preventing the postgis adapter from parsing that value back into a geometry type. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31170056/83743 for how to fix that.