# activerecord_postgis_adapter: undefined method `point' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgis, geos, rgeo

## Problem

90% sure it's a setup error on my end, but I can't do self.factory and trying to access lonlat gives me an exception "undefined method `point' for nil:NilClass"

## I can

Set lonlat using:

```
mfactory = RGeo::ActiveRecord::SpatialFactoryStore.instance.factory(:geo_type => 'point')
self.lonlat = mfactory.point(long, lat)
self.save
```

This gives me values like `0101000020E610000061C3D32B65965DC03657CD7344F64040` in the db.

I can't use:

```
self.lonlat = "POINT(#{long},#{lat})"
self.save
```

## Questions

Do I need to setup something specific in the model?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[I created a github issue with a less consise but more detailed explaination.](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter/issues/190)

RGeos depends on GEOS. This error is a result of RGeos not being able to load GEOS.

To check if this is the issue:

```
$ rails c
> RGeo::Geos.supported?
=> false
```

To check if you have GEOS installed:

```
geos-config --version
```

If GEOS isn't installed:

```
brew install geos
```

If GEOS is installed, fix your installed RGeo:

```
$ geos-config --prefix
/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.5.0
$ gem install rgeo -- --with-geos-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.5.0
```

Should now be installed correctly and your errors fixed. You can check as we did above:

```
$ rails c
> RGeo::Geos.supported?
=> true
```

If this doesn't work uninstall ALL versions of geos and rgeo:

```
$ brew uninstall geos
$ gem uninstall rgeo
```

Re-install geos and rgeo as instructed above. You should have gem 'rgeo' in your Gemfile and after you bundle, you should see this as one of the outputs: "Installing rgeo 0.4.0 with native extensions"