# setting up RoR with rgeo on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rgeo

I am trying to get my RoR app up and running on Elastic Beanstalk and am struggling to get the rgeo gem working.  The error I am getting on the web server is:

```
I, [2015-09-28T11:26:54.982049 #21789]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal     Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
F, [2015-09-28T11:26:54.983523 #21789] FATAL -- : 
NoMethodError (undefined method `point' for nil:NilClass):
  lib/app/weather_service.rb:61:in `block in get_location'
  ....
```

That error happens when the code accesses a model attribute that is backed by a POINT data type in the database.  The error is typically due to a missing dependency, namely geos as described in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31170055/activerecord-postgis-adapter-undefined-method-point-for-nilnilclass).  So I connected to the underlying EC2 instance, installed geos and re-installed the rgeo gem.  That resolved the issue in rails console:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx ~]$ cd /var/app/current
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx current]$ rails c
Loading production environment (Rails 4.2.4)
irb(main):001:0> RGeo::Geos.supported?
=> true
```

That did not, however, resolve the error in the web server.  I'm pretty sure I don't clearly understand the Elastic Beanstalk environment and maybe making direct changes to the underlying EC2 instance won't make dependencies available to the application instance.  I do understand that I would need to either add the dependencies to either a custom AMI or ebextensions for future deployments, but I wanted to make sure I have the dependencies working before going through that process.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this same issue, I did find a solution.  These are the steps I followed:

- Created an EC2 instance using AMI ami-bddbc48d
- Installed the PostGIS dependencies using this helpful script https://gist.github.com/whyvez/8d19096712ea44ba66b0
- Created a custom AMI from that instance
- Updated my EBS environment configuration to use that new custom AMI
- Voila! Problem solved